# What is wrong with this form autofill javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, autofill

It is called from the browser and should expand the "select" menu with the name 7725, and then 1 second later select the menu option with the data-id of 18726.

The menu expands as if it was clicked, but I can not get it to select the option.

```
var element = document.getElementsByName("7725")[0];

var element2 = document.querySelectorAll('[data-id="18726"]')[0];

var dispatchMouseEvent = function(target, var_args) {
  var e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
  e.initMouseEvent.apply(e, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
  target.dispatchEvent(e);
};

dispatchMouseEvent(element, 'mouseover', true, true);
dispatchMouseEvent(element, 'mousedown', true, true);
dispatchMouseEvent(element, 'click', true, true);
dispatchMouseEvent(element, 'mouseup', true, true);

var func = function () {
dispatchMouseEvent(element2, 'mouseover', true, true);
dispatchMouseEvent(element2, 'mousedown', true, true);
dispatchMouseEvent(element2, 'click', true, true);
dispatchMouseEvent(element2, 'mouseup', true, true);}
setTimeout(func, 1000);
```

html

```
<select data-widget-cid="widget-1" class="ui-dropdown ui-dropdown-system" data-role="content" name="7725">
<option data-role="item" value="" data-id="">--Please select--</option>
<option data-role="item" value="100018726-IE 1" data-id="18726">IE 1</option>
<option data-role="item" value="100018727-IE 2" data-id="18727">IE 2</option>
<option data-role="item" value="100018728-IE 3" data-id="18728">IE 3</option>
<option data-role="item" value="100018729-IE 4" data-id="18729">IE 4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: can you give some html?

Comment: @SufianSaory I updated it with example html, thanks

Comment: Anybody?......... :(

Comment: when i run your code in chrome i get the following warning "A DOM event generated from JavaScript has triggered a default action inside the browser. This behavior is non-standard and will be removed in M53, around September 2016. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5718803933560832 for more details.". perhaps for security issue it's not allowing.

Comment: If that were it, I guess the first menu selection wouldn't work, according to that page the dom event should be enabled by default in version 53. Seems like it's something else maybe

Comment: any other way to simulate a selection by keyboard or mouse?

Comment: perhaps you can use jQuery for it. let me add it as an answer.

Comment: do you must do it in plain JavaScript?

Comment: @SufianSaory I thought I could do it with jquery by adding jquery through the console but content security won't let me insert the code. So I guess I can only use plain javascript. It's helpful to see how it could be done in jquery though, thanks!

Comment: I've updated the answer with a plain JavaScript version.

Answer (score 0):

here is the plain JavaScript version to auto select the option with with the data-id of 18726

```
var getIndexOf = function (id) {
    var options = document.getElementsByTagName('option');
    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        if (id == options[i].getAttribute('data-id')) {
            return i;
        }
    }
};
var el = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
el.selectedIndex = getIndexOf('18726');
```